# Different time range per field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My index contains documents with fields called *send_date* and *tags*. Currently I'm fetching documents which contains any tag specified by the user.

Exemplary query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"this is tag1\" \"this is tag2\"",
      "fields": ["tags"],
      "default_operator": "OR"
    }
  }
}
```

But now I'd like to query my index to return me documents which contains:

- *this is tag1* and were send in date range (a, b)

or

- *this is tag2* and were send in date range (c, d)

Is this is possible using single query and some mix of *bool / range* queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to stick to `query_string`, you can do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(tags:\"this is tag1\" AND date:[2020-01-01 TO 2021-01-01]) OR (tags:\"this is tag2\" AND date:[2020-06-01 TO 2020-07-01])",
      "default_operator": "OR"
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can leverage `range` queries and combine them with the `query_string` one in a `bool/should`combo:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "tags:\"this is tag1\"",
                  "default_operator": "OR"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "date": {
                    "gte": "2020-01-01",
                    "lte": "2021-01-01"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "tags:\"this is tag2\"",
                  "default_operator": "OR"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "date": {
                    "gte": "2020-06-01",
                    "lte": "2020-07-01"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```